# Exporting .dae file from Blender and import it on Processing

Tags: animation, objects, baking, collada

What I am trying to do is export from Blender a .dae file of an animated object and then import this file on processing and use it there. I created a rotating cube, baked action and exported it as .dae file. the problem is when I am importing it on processing the animation doesn't work and I can see only a square.

```
import ch.dieseite.colladaloader.ColladaLoader;
import ch.dieseite.colladaloader.wrappers.ColladaModel;

ColladaModel model;

void setup() {
  size(500,600,P3D);
  background(255);
  lights();
  frameRate(10);
  model = ColladaLoader.load("cuberot.dae", this, null);
  model.scale(25);
}

void draw() {
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  model.draw(); 
}
```

Can someone explain how this can work? 
Also why I have to scale my object in order to see it properly? if don't the object is like a pixel.

Comment: You mean the Processing framework, correct? Perhaps their importer doesn't support animations yet and therefore has trouble properly reading Blender's dae?

Comment: I followed this http://www.die-seite.ch/?colladaloader and imported the library on Processing. Maybe some other idea how to do it? Thanks.